# Postgresql fatal error could not load pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to fix my pg_hba.conf file and it should be easy. The /var/log file says:

```
2023-03-14 12:13:31.515 CET [9199] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-03-14 12:13:31.539 CET [9199] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2023-03-14 12:13:31.539 CET [9199] CONTEXT:  line 99 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-03-14 12:13:31.539 CET [9199] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2023-03-14 12:13:31.546 CET [9199] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Line 99 is the one IPv4 line and I've deleted and retyped, copied other lines to try and remove the error but it hasn't worked.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             "pi-ita"                                peer
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all                                     md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

The user is pi-ita.

Comment: It is, the line was cut off by nano when displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure if the quotes around the user are necessary or not but I've tried both with and without

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue to be with not defining the address for host in IPv4 connections.

The pg_hba.conf was changed to:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32         md5
```

and the connections can be made again.